# не выводит данные php+mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, вывод

Возник вопрос - разрабатываю новостную форму для сайта и тем же пытаюсь изучать ООП.

```
$obj=new news();
$result = $obj->get_news();
while($output = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 echo '<div class="product">
        <div class="product_image">
          <image src="/images/'.$output["id"].'.jpg" />
        </div>
        <h2>
        '.$output["name"].'
        </h2>
        <div class="product_price">
        '.$output["price"].' $.
        </div>
        <div class="product_buy">
        <a href="/">korzina</a>
        </div>
      </div>';
}
```

и функция из news:

```
require 'displaynews.php';
public $db;
public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
        exit;
        }
public function get_news(){
                $query = 'SELECT name, price FROM news';
 $result = $this -> mysqli -> query($query);
        return $result;
                }


Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
```

Ругается на строчку:

```
 $result = $this -> mysqli -> query($query);
```

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы бы констрактор привели. А то не ясно где и как вы инициализируете   mysqli

Comment: include "db_config.php";

public function __construct(){
   $this->db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
   exit;
   }
  }

Comment: @newuser отредактируйте свой вопрос, и вставьте этот код туда

Comment: Не понимаю, почему вы при инициализации делаете `$this->db = ...`, а обращаетесь как `$this->mysqli` вы уж определитесь с именем переменной

Comment: @Mike благодарю! все заработало. 
тема закрыта.